# Which pattern for wrapping NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, nsuserdefaults

My apps use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] as a quick and dirty database to store state about the user and the app itself. The trouble with NSUserDefaults is that its flexibility allows for a big mess down the line, for example when different files all set and read different keys in the dictionary in their own way. You don't get to enforce rules, you can screw up the key name etc..

I wrote a simple singleton "manager-style" wrapper for NSUserDefaults which both takes care of setting the default values when used, hides the name of keys used to fetch the values and encapsulates some extra logic, such as encoding to NSData, when storing and retrieving objects from the store.

At this point they're properties backed by a read/set accessor, but something is rubbing me wrong about it and I'm wondering if perhaps there's a more elegant way of achieving the same result. There's quite a bit of boilerplate and the syntax ends up being somewhat unpleasant. To give you an example:

.h:

```
@interface UserDefaultsManager: NSObject

+ (UserDefaultsManager *)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger somethingImTracking;

@end
```

and .m:

```
NSString * const kSomethingImTracking= @"SomethingImTracking";

@implementation UserDefaultsManager

[...]

- (NSInteger)somethingImTracking
{
    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSomethingImTracking] intValue];
}

- (void)setSomethingImTracking:(NSInteger)somethingImTracking
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:somethingImTracking forKey:kSomethingImTracking];
}
```

and to access:

```
NSInteger foo = [UserDefaultsManager sharedInstance].somethingImTracking;
```

Comment: I'm doing *exactly* the same thing in one of my apps to encapsulate a set of preference settings my app supports. BTW - you should make kSomethingImTracking static since it is only used in this .m file.

Comment: You might also want your `setSomethingImTracking` such that (a) it might be prudent to do `synchronize` after setting the value; and (b) maybe do `willChangeValueForKey` before setting the value and `didChangeValueForKey` after setting it, in case you ever implement KVO in the future. But I agree that this is a good way to isolate the particulars of your `NSUserDefaults` settings.

Comment: @Rob Can you elaborate more on synchronize? I always thought that synchronize was mostly useful when you knew your app was about to suddenly terminate, and that every remaining scenario should be usually taken care of by the system automatically. I'm concerned that there might be performance repercussions with forcing it to persist data to disk in the main thread.

Comment: @AlexandrKurilin There is a performance hit, though I don't know how observable it is. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-97569) are a little ambiguous as to when the automatic sync takes place. For me, `NSUserDefaults` rarely changes, so when it does, I just `synchronize`. I'd rather it be deterministic, `synchronize` when I want. You can probably solve that by dispatching the synchronize to a background queue if you're concerned.

Comment: Unnecessary synchronization (and on 10.8+ that's "virtually all synchronization") is immensely slower, though still not all that bad. Don't do it, it's voodoo, and you should understand how NSUserDefaults works instead. If you see a case in a 10.8+ single-process Mac app where synchronize is useful, that's worth filing a bug about. It shouldn't be (multi-process, non-NSApplication, and iOS are still slightly more complicated, but even there the rules for when synchronize is needed aren't hard)

Comment: Also, a background queue won't help. You'll still be holding CFPreferences internal locks and blocking reads from the app's domain while the synch is in progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I use string constants to store the key names, and just access the user defaults object directly, but I don't tend to use defaults to a huge extent, or in many different classes.

One improvement I'd make to your code is to have them all as class methods instead. There is no benefit to a singleton (you're not maintaining any state, that's all in the defaults object) and this takes a bit of the ugly repetitive code (`...sharedInstance`) out of your use pattern.

`synchronize` is not necessary to include every time you set. It is only needed when accessing defaults values from different threads in quick succession. The OS calls it itself periodically as well.

Comment: That's a good point, I am certainly unnecessarily "futureproofing" the class for potential future internal state. The only advantage the singleton offers is to lazily run "registerDefaults" whenever it's used for the first time, which is easily replaced with a separate call in the app delegate code.

Comment: Another advantage to having the singleton is for supplying the NSUserDefaults instance you're going to use. You could have a static property, but that seems like a mess. And really you may only care about dependency injection if you're going to be writing tests or are an OOP pedant.

Comment: @rob5408 in iOS, there is only one defaults instance.

Comment: @jrturton, there certainly is, but for mocking you may want to pass in your own NSUserDefaults object. It can also save you a million [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] calls.

Comment: If you eschew static methods you've got something you can easily mock in a unit test. That alone is worth it.